# Sending email asynchronously with attachment in Django

Tags: django, email

I am using below code to send email with pdf attachment. But, it is thowing an error - "assertion no content". I am not sure why it is so. I am able to send the email with pdf synchronously as well as send email async with no pdf.
(Using Django 1.3)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
import threading
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class EmailThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, subject, body, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, html,pdf):
        self.subject = subject
        self.body = body
        self.recipient_list = recipient_list
        self.from_email = from_email
        self.fail_silently = fail_silently
        self.html = html
        self.pdf = pdf
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(self.subject, self.body, self.from_email, self.recipient_list)
        msg.attach('ticket.pdf',self.pdf,'application/pdf')
        if self.html:
            msg.attach_alternative(self.html, "text/html")
        msg.send(self.fail_silently)


def send_mail(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=True, html=None,pdf=None, *args, **kwargs):
    EmailThread(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, html, pdf).start()
```

Comment: What are pdf and html when you call send_mail? (These are the two things that get checked with `assert content is not None` in django.core.mail.message.) Is it possible that somehow pdf is getting altered between the time you call send_mail and the time the send thread is run?

Comment: Also, FYI, there's an app called django-mailer that implements a (reasonably-)robust async send queue. It handles cases like retrying later if msg.send fails the first time through. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it might be a better approach than using threads like this.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens with your code when you try to send an email without an attachment, as is quite expected with `send_mail`.

```
  def run(self):
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(self.subject, self.body, self.from_email, self.recipient_list)
        msg.attach('ticket.pdf',self.pdf,'application/pdf')
        #                       ^^^^^^^^ is None. 
        if self.html:
            msg.attach_alternative(self.html, "text/html")
        msg.send(self.fail_silently)
```

Yes, you would end up trying to attach a file with no content. You need to make sure you only attach only if there's something to attach. What would be the point anyways? Some `ticket.pdf` that's an empty string?

Also, I second the idea of using `django-mailer`.